# Particles JS - How to change background color between lines?

Tags: javascript, particles

Please, I need help...

I have to create a particles JS canvas. It's not really difficult but I have to change the background color between each lines like this :

EXAMPLE
[image]

I browsed all setting provide by particles JS but nothing did something like I need...
If Someone could help me and provide me some code, that will be really kind.

Thank's you very much

Comment: Kevin, have you fond the answer? I'm also looking for it without success..

Comment: Nope... Sorry..., Finally I did something with no different colors

Answer (score 3):

Kevin, i've found the solution. You can specify the color using 'color' attribute from 'particles' param. Here's an example from my applicaiton. (I'm using angular with typescript):

```
 <particles [style]="style" [width]="width" [height]="height" [params]="params"></particles>
```

On the view side specify params and then add actual params object inside the component. In my case it's:

```
this.params = {
      particles: {
        number: {
          value: 100,
        },
        color: {
          value: ['#858585']
        },
        line_linked: {
          color: '#f44242',
          opacity: 1
        }
      }
    };
```

So you'll have particles of color: #858585
And all of your connections between nodes will be colored in: #f44242

Hope it helps! =)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how you can create this effect with particleJS but you can try [Trianglify.js](https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify) which pretty much creates the same effect you want. You can look up tessellation effect with js and you might find some effects similar to this. If you want some code I pulled this off the quickstart code from Trianglify.js:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trianglify/2.0.0/trianglify.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pattern = Trianglify({
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
});
document.body.appendChild(pattern.canvas())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom css file with the following and it should work.

```
#particles-js {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```